# Examples of when it is convenient to use Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

Tags: java, multithreading, pooling

Could please somebody tell me a real life example where it's convenient to use this factory method rather than others?

> newSingleThreadExecutor
>
> public static ExecutorService newSingleThreadExecutor()
>
> Creates an Executor that uses a single worker thread operating off an
>   unbounded queue. (Note however that if this single thread terminates
>   due to a failure during execution prior to shutdown, a new one will
>   take its place if needed to execute subsequent tasks.) Tasks are
>   guaranteed to execute sequentially, and no more than one task will be
>   active at any given time. Unlike the otherwise equivalent
>   newFixedThreadPool(1) the returned executor is guaranteed not to be
>   reconfigurable to use additional threads.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Could please somebody tell me a real life example where it's convenient to use [the `newSingleThreadExecutor()` factory method] rather than others?

I assume you are asking about when you use a single-threaded thread-pool as opposed to a fixed or cached thread pool.

I use a single threaded executor when I have many tasks to run but I only want one thread to do it.  This is the same as using a fixed thread pool of 1 of course.  Often this is because we don't need them to run in parallel, they are background tasks, and we don't want to take too many system resources (CPU, memory, IO).  I want to deal with the various tasks as `Callable` or `Runnable` objects so an `ExecutorService` is optimal but all I need is a single thread to run them.

For example, I have a number of timer tasks that I spring inject.  I have two kinds of tasks and my "short-run" tasks run in a single thread pool.  There is only one thread that executes them all even though there are a couple of hundred in my system.  They do routine tasks such as checking for disk space, cleaning up logs, dumping statistics, etc.. For the tasks that are time critical, I run in a cached thread pool.

Another example is that we have a series of partner integration tasks.  They don't take very long and they run rather infrequently and we don't want them to compete with other system threads so they run in a single threaded executor.

A third example is that we have a finite state machine where each of the state mutators takes the job from one state to another and is registered as a `Runnable` in a single thread-pool.  Even though we have hundreds of mutators, only one task is valid at any one point in time so it makes no sense to allocate more than one thread for the task.

Comment: Because we don't want them to run in parallel and consume too many CPU resources @Rollerball.  I've added another example which shows that.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the reasons already mentioned, you would want to use a single threaded executor when you want ordering guarantees, i.e you need to make sure that whatever tasks are being submitted will always happen in the order they were submitted.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` and `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)` is small but can be helpful when designing a library API. If you expose the returned `ExecutorService` to users of your library and the library works correctly only when the executor uses a single thread (tasks are not thread safe), it is preferable to use `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`. Otherwise the user of your library could break it by doing this:

```
ExecutorService e = myLibrary.getBackgroundTaskExecutor();
((ThreadPoolExecutor)e).setCorePoolSize(10);
```

, which is not possible for `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`.

Answer (score 0):

It is helpful when you need a lightweight service which only makes it convenient to defer task execution, and you want to ensure only one thread is used for the job.